# thread parameter passing c

Tags: c, multithreading, parameter-passing

My question regards parameter passing to a thread.

I have a function Foo that operates on an array, say arrayA. To speed things up, Foo is coded to operate at both directions on the array. So, Foo takes arrayA and an integer X as parameters. Depending on the value of X, it operates in forward or reverse direction.

I'm looking to avoid making global use of "arrayA" and "X". So, I'm after passing "arrayA" and "X" as parameters to Foo, and creating two threads to run Foo-- one in each direction. Here's what I did:

```
typedef struct {int* arrayA[MSIZE]; int X; } TP; //arrayPack=TP 

void Foo (void *tP) {

    TP *tp = (TP*)tP;  // cast the parameter tP back to what it is and assign to pointer *tp

    int x;
    printf("\nX: %d", tp->X);
    printf("\n  arrayA: "); for (x=0; x<tp->arrayA.size(); printf("%d ", aP->arrayA[x]), x++);  
} // end Foo

void callingRouting ()  {   
    int* arrayA[MSIZE] = {3,5,7,9}; 
    TP tp; tp.arrayA=arrayA; 
    tp.X=0;   _beginthread(Foo, 0, (void*)&tp); // process -- forward 
    tp.X=1;   _beginthread(Foo, 0, (void*)&tp); // process -- reverse   
}
```

The values aren`t passed-- my array is printing empty and I'm not getting the value of X printed right. What am i missing ?

I would also appreciate suggestions on some readings on this-- passing parameters to threads-- especially on passing the resources shared by the threads. Thanks.

Comment: `int *arrayA[MSIZE];` is probably the wrong size.

Comment: as a side note, I don't see where you're doing the reverse iteration.  I would actually recommend using offsets into the array vs an offset so you could be more scalable to more threads.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the address of a stack variable to your thread function, once `callingRouting` exits the `TP` structure no longer exists. They need to be either globals or allocated on the heap.

However you'll need two copies of the `TP` for each thread as the change `tp.X=1` may be visible to both threads.

There are problems there but how you see them depends on how the OS decides to schedule the threads on each execution.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm loading `tp.X` to a local variable so that it wont be seen by the other thread of Foo. haven't gone so far as trying this yet. and i guess the other Foo/thread can change `tp.X` value before i load it to some local variable. 

i'm alright that TP no longer is there once callingRoutine exits. my problem is not being able to pass `arrayA` and `X` to Foo. And how to pass them "by value" and "by reference".

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember is that you have a thread that is starting up two other threads.  Since you do not have any control over the processor time slice and how that is allocated, you can not be sure when the two other threads will start and may be not even the order that they will start in.

Since you hare using an array on the stack that is local to the function `callingRouting ()` as soon as that function returns the local variables allocated will basically be out of scope and can no longer be depended on.

So there are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is to use global or static memory variables for these data items being passed to the threads.

The other is to start both threads and then wait for both to complete before continuing.

Since you do not know when or the order of the threads being started, you really should use two different TP type variables, one for each thread.  Otherwise you run the risk of the time slice allocation to be such that both threads will have the same TP data.

Comment: OK, here's 2quick notes on this-- to clarify some and avoid things in wrong direction:

the output of Foo is another array, say `Z`. `arrayA` is a "work area" only and doesn't matter whether changes on it wont be seen outside Foo. 

However, the changes to `arrayA` done by one thread of Foo should be seen by the other Foo thread. Thats why i've been looking to pass the reference of `tp` to Foo. Foo should be reading/writing to a mem.location passed to it by the calling parameter. & i should be passing the reference of that location to both threads of Foo so that they R/W on the same arrayA.